# Why does document's readystate change from "complete" to "loading"?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Please take a look at the following code:

```js
this.detachedWin = window.open(window.origin + "/@/tab","Detached","menubar=0,toolbar=0,personalbar=0,status=0");
  
this.doc = this.detachedWin.document;

setInterval(() => {
  console.log(this.doc === this.detachedWin.document,this.detachedWin.document.readyState);
  this.doc = this.detachedWin.document;
}, 10);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reza_karimi76/95heugm0/22/)

If you take a look at your console log, you see something like this:

[image]

I don't underestand why the ready state of document is "complete" at the first time and what is the reason it changes to loading after that?
I expect that the ready state to be "loading" for the first time.

Comment: There is something wrong with jsFiddle test-case, getting undefined document.

Comment: @lortschi I double checked it. It works as expected. Please try to open it with Chrome and press F12 and look at console. Don't look at the embedded console of JSFiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First "complete" happens with blank window, and then it changes location to provided URL.

> Note that remote URLs won't load immediately. When window.open()
> returns, the window always contains about:blank. The actual fetching
> of the URL is deferred and starts after the current script block
> finishes executing. The window creation and the loading of the
> referenced resource are done asynchronously.
>
> [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#description)

### Simplified window opening flow

1. ***window.open()***
2. Immediately loaded, because nothing to load: "loading"
3. Immediately become interactive, because it's empty: "interactive"
4. Blank window is ready: "completed"
5. **Set *window.location* explicitly or implicitly**
6. Redirect to URL: "loading"
7. Window become interactive: "interactive"
8. Window is ready: "completed"

Full flow with all steps for window opening you can find in [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#window-open-steps).

To see how it works, check example:

```js
const openMe = () => { 
  this.detachedWin = window.open("", "Detached","menubar=0,toolbar=0,personalbar=0,status=0");

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("loading happen now")
    this.detachedWin.location = window.origin + "/@/tab"
  }, 1000);

  this.doc = this.detachedWin.document;
  setInterval(() => {
    console.log(this.doc === this.detachedWin.document, this.detachedWin.document.readyState);
    this.doc = this.detachedWin.document;
  }, 10);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="openMe()">Open window</button>
```

Comment: So the `readystate` flag is kind of useless since you don't know which document is loaded, blank or original document. I think the best way is to define your flag is `onload` event of your document and work with that.

Comment: Yes, you right. Feel free to mark this question as resolved